# is there a solution to remove lint from xcode project and every thing related?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, lint

I'm working on a project with my friend and we sometimes share the project zip file without Source Controllers like GitLab. When I get and rebuild the project I face the error: **${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint causes Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**

I tried to remove lint by uninstalling from pods but now I get this error:

**/project_address/Pods/Target Support Files/SwiftLint/SwiftLint.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "SwiftLint" in project "Pods")**

could some body help me find the solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: SwiftLint is being executed on a script added in build phases.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the pod:

```
pod 'SwiftLint'
```

2. Remove the run script that looks like this:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint"
```

3. Remove any custom configurations files that you *may* added with `.swiftlint.yml` extension from the directory that you are running SwiftLint from

Comment: I did this but the error still exists
**/project_address/Pods/Target Support Files/SwiftLint/SwiftLint.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "SwiftLint" in project "Pods")**
I even deleted .swiftlint.yml file

Comment: Did you run `pod install` after deleting the pod?

Comment: Try `pod deintegrate`

Comment: I did all the above 

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. After doing all the steps above I removed "${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint" from "project settings/target/build phase/run script" and works like a charm.